# QtCreator Не запускается .exe

Tags: qtcreator, windows-7

При запуске проекта состоящего нескольких файлов, после сборки ( сборка проходит без ошибок) не запускается .exe из IDE ( нажатие зеленой стрелки )

Ошибка (вкладка Вывод приложения):

> 10:32:22: D:/Geo/Test/test/release/test завершился с кодом -1073741511

Когда же копирую .exe в папку `C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin` он запускается без проблем

В переменной Path путь `C:\Qt\5.7\mingw53_32\bin` прописан

OC: Windows7

[image: Пример проекта с ошибкой]

Comment: Из IDE тоже не запускается?

Comment: Как раз из нее и не запускается, уточнил в тексте вопроса